# Electron js - Sub divs like dropdowns crops when parent window is smaller

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, openfin

When I minimize the size of my application window and open a div (dropdown or any other menu), if the size of that div is bigger than the parent window, div is cropped.[screenshot from intelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuEOo.png)

In some applications like Intellij IDEA, they handle it well.[screenshot from my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XolO.jpg)

Comment: You can't. As long as you are rendering the dropdown in html, it must be inside the browser frame.

Comment: Thank you @Luke , If there is any other way like, shrinking the sub-div on scale ??